# How to create a Highcharts heat map chart that represent different categories and filer the data for each category?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am new to `Highcharts` and am looking for an example of a heatmap where I can filter the data based on the different category selectors. What I am looking for is the ability to see the positive prices in green color and the one with negatives in red color, and the darkness of those colors consistent with funds.

Here's an example of the visualization that I am trying to achieve:

```
      |                                  Select Category               
      |                             [checkbox] Prime
Price |  30%                        [checkbox] Government and Treasury
      |  20%                        [checkbox] Tax Exempt
      |
      |__ __ __ __ __ __ __ __
            weeks
```

The chart should display histogram of the data for the reported number of rows that occurs between certain week. The data also needs to be broken down into what category and fund type it belongs to. Each categories have several different fund types. The user should be able to select which category and its corresponding fund type data they want to see on the chart. Based on their selection, that's the data they see on the chart.

Here's an example of the desired output that I am looking for:
[image: chart]

Here's the data that I need to visualize and build charts from:

```
CATEGORY       |                     FUND_TYPE     | 10/7/2016 | 10/14/2016 | 10/21/2016 |  10/28/2016   | 11/4/2016 |  11/11/2016
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Prime                       Prime Institutional       1             1            1              1.0001          0         0       
  Prime                       Prime Retail                    0           0            0             0            1.0001      1.0001
  Prime                       Prime Institutional       1             1          1.0001         1.0002        1.0002      1.0002
  Prime                       Prime Institutional       1             1          1.0001         1.0002        1.0002      1.0002
  Prime                       Prime Institutional       1             1          1.0001         1.0002        1.0002      1.0002
  Prime                       Prime Institutional       1             1          1.0001         1.0002        1.0002      1.0002
Government and Treasury           Government          1.0005        1.0005       1.0005         1.0005        1.0005      1.0004
Prime                           Prime Institutional   0.9998        0.9997       0.9998         0.9999            0          0
Prime                           Prime Retail                      0           0            0              0           0.9999       0.9999
Tax Exempt                    Tax Exempt Retail     0.9996      0.9996       0.9996         0.9996        0.9996       0.9996
Tax Exempt                    Tax Exempt Inst.        1           1            1                1                1          1
Tax Exempt                    Tax Exempt Inst.        1           1            1                1                1          1
Tax Exempt                    Tax Exempt Inst.        1           1            1                1                1          1
Tax Exempt                    Tax Exempt Inst.        1           1            1                1                1          1
Government and Treasury            Treasury         1.0002     1.0003          1.0003           1.0003         1.0003       1.0003
Government and Treasury            Treasury         1.0002     1.0003          1.0003           1.0003         1.0003       1.0003
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Shaun, I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w45nxLc1/ As you can see, you change change chart data in a simple way.

Comment: @ppotaczek thank you for getting back to me. Let me update my post again so you can have a better idea what I am looking for. I got some more info now regarding the chart that I would like to share to see if you can help me accomplish that.

Comment: @ppotaczek just updated my post if you can please help with this.

Comment: @ppotaczek I just created another post and was able to put together a data into the chart. All I need help now is with filtering the data and updating the chart. Can you please take a look at this new post that I created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66736075/how-to-make-buttons-filter-different-data-based-on-a-category-they-select-in-hig