# How to make buttons filter different data based on a category they select in Highcharts heatmap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, heatmap

I have a heatmap that needs to be updated based on the different categories the user selects. Each category has their own sub-categories. For ex:

```
Prime: 
  'Prime Institutional' 
  'Prime Retail'
Government and Treasury: 
  'Government' 
  'Treasury'
Tax Exempt: 
  'Tax Exempt Retail' 
  'Tax Exempt Institutional'
```

This is how the data looks like in excel sheet.
[image]

Can someone please help me add this functionality to my chart?

```
function get_data() {
            // Need to determine which elements are selected
            let selected = ['Prime Institutional', 'Government'];

            let result = {};

            selected.forEach(sel => {
                Object.keys(data[sel]).forEach(date => {
                    Object.keys(data[sel][date]).forEach(price => {
                        // Skip prices that fall outside the range
                        if ((price < ymin) || (price > ymax)) {
                            return;
                        }
                        // Create the maps if they don't exist
                        if (result[date] === undefined) {
                            result[date] = {};
                        }
                        if (result[date][price] === undefined) {
                            result[date][price] = {};
                        }
                        
                        // Set the value
                        result[date][price] = data[sel][date][price];
                    })
                })
            });

            // Make the data
            let new_data = [];
            Object.keys(result).forEach(date => {
                Object.keys(result[date]).forEach(price => {
                    // console.log(parseFloat(price));
                    new_data.push({
                        x: parseInt(date),
                        y: (parseFloat(price)*10000),
                        value: result[date][price]
                    });
                });
            });
            chart.series[0].setData(new_data);
        }
```

An example of jsfiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/oyzw75xj/4/

Comment: its not clear, what do you want? i see you have 3 buttons and each button is the title of main category and then?

Comment: Hi @Frenchy thanks for the response. I just updated my post with the picture of the data in excel. Basically, what I am looking for is the ability to select which category the user wants to see data on the chart. Depending on their selection, the chart should update dynamically. Does that help at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a parameter to your function, for example `selected` and build data structure based on that parameter.

```
document.getElementById('primeBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    set_data(['Prime Retail', 'Prime Institutional']);
});

document.getElementById('govtTreasBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    set_data(['Treasury', 'Government']);
});

document.getElementById('taxExmptBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    set_data(['Tax Exempt Institutional', 'Tax Exempt Retail']);
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/df4urhva/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData